# Cannot fill fully cells in Microsoft Word table

Tags: microsoft-word

In normal cases using Microsoft Word, after selecting cells in a table, chose Shading, the cells will be filled in a whole, as in table A.

But now I have a table that would not fill the center part, as in Table B.

What happened? How could I fill the cells as a whole?

[image]

Comment: Try selecting the whole cell **not** the text within the cell ...

Comment: @DavidPostill i did select by cell, actually i selected two cells.

Comment: Your question saved my entire day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible cause:

The style of the text has a background shading pattern applied, and that "overrides" the background formatting of the cells.

To check, select some of the text, then open the Styles Pane (e.g. Alt-Ctrl-Shift-S). The current style should be selected. (If you are not aware of applying any particular style, it is probably Normal, so ensure that is selected).

Click the Style Inspector button at the bottom of the dialog (it looks like an "A" with a small magnifying glass.)

Look at the "Plus" boxes under both "Paragraph level formatting" and "Text level formatting". here, for example, I made a change which means I see "Plus: Clear Background 1" in the Text formatting section.

I was able to clear that by clicking the "Clear All" button, but of course that may have an impact on *all* the text of that style and all the text of styles based on that style, so you may need to explore further before making that change.

I have not explored *all* possibilities in this area - for example, there might be some settings in a Table Style that have a similar effect, but I am reasonably confidant that this is the general area that you need to look at.

Comment: it works like a charm :) thank you.

Comment: You are the one. Saved my life